# How do I plot this time series?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot this time series in a chart, but the canvas is empty.

[image: Screenshot of my code]
As you can see in the image above, my time series is quite simple. I want to plot DATE in x-axis and PAYEMS in the y-axis.

At first, I was getting an error because my dates were strings, so I converted it in cell 11.

Comment: Try not to post images, but formatted code that allow copy/paste. It will be easier to help you.

Comment: Thank you, @FabienP, for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want to use a `tsplot` to plot a time series. The name is a bit confusing, but as the documentation puts it,  `tsplot` is *"intended to be used with data where observations are nested within sampling units that were measured at multiple timepoints"*.  As a rule of thumb: If you understand this sentence, you will know when to use it, if you don't understand this sentence, don't use it. Apart, `tsplot` will even be removed or significantly altered in the future, so its use is deprecated.

But that doesn't matter, because you can directly use pandas to plot the time series.

```
df.plot(x="Date", y="Payems")
```

Comment: Thank you! The `tsplot` is indeed confused and all I needed was `dt.plot`.